# Add vertical polylines of specific length to contiguous polygons in R

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon, spatial, polyline

I'm attempting to pro-grammatically add multiple vertical polylines of specific length to contiguous polygons in R. The number and length of the polylines should be specified by the user and can range from 1 to 8 polylines and 5000 to 10000 feet long per contiguous polygons. How can I achieve this in R?

I'm able to do this manually by the use of the `mapedit` package for a couple of polygons but I would like to automate the process for several thousand contiguous polygons.

```
# Load required libraries
library(mapedit)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)

# Sample polygons and polylines
geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(8.769563, 8.769563, 
                                                     8.770507, 8.770507, 8.769563, 50.815273, 50.815714, 50.815714, 
                                                     50.815273, 50.815273), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
                                                                                                          "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(8.769568, 8.769568, 8.770507, 
                                                                                                                                              8.770507, 8.769568, 50.814852, 50.81527, 50.81527, 50.814852, 
                                                                                                                                              50.814852), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                              )), structure(list(structure(c(8.769568, 8.769568, 8.770502, 
                                                                                                                                                                             8.770502, 8.769568, 50.814412, 50.814849, 50.814849, 50.814412, 
                                                                                                                                                                             50.814412), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                                                             )), structure(list(structure(c(8.769568, 8.769568, 8.770502, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            8.770502, 8.769568, 50.814005, 50.814408, 50.814408, 50.814005, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            50.814005), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                                                                                            )), structure(list(structure(c(8.770502, 8.770502, 8.771301, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           8.771301, 8.770502, 50.815273, 50.815717, 50.815717, 50.815273, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           50.815273), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           )), structure(list(structure(c(8.770518, 8.770518, 8.771301, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          8.771301, 8.770518, 50.814852, 50.81527, 50.81527, 50.814852, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          50.814852), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          )), structure(list(structure(c(8.770507, 8.770507, 8.771301, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         8.771301, 8.770507, 50.814408, 50.814849, 50.814849, 50.814408, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         50.814408), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         )), structure(list(structure(c(8.770507, 8.770507, 8.771296, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        8.771296, 8.770507, 50.814005, 50.814405, 50.814405, 50.814005, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        50.814005), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        )), structure(c(8.769794, 8.769783, 50.814785, 50.814076), .Dim = c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(8.770051, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    8.770035, 50.814785, 50.814069), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(8.770271, 8.77026, 50.814781, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    50.814076), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ))), class = c("sfc_GEOMETRY", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 8.769563, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ymin = 50.814005, xmax = 8.771301, ymax = 50.815717), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), classes = c("POLYGON", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "POLYGON", "LINESTRING", "LINESTRING", "LINESTRING"), n_empty = 0L)

# Visualize geometry
mapview(geometry)
```

[image]

I attempted to create regularly sampled points via the `spsample` function inside the polygons and connecting them by lines but was unsuccessful.  appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Could you clarify the specifications of the lines? Are there any constraints on the lines (apart from fitting in the polygon)? Should the lines be random? All parallel (as in your illustration)? Not cross? Or just lines that fit in you polygons?

Comment: @EtienneRacine. The lines should be parallel and fit inside the polygons (1 mile by 1 mile). Their length and count can vary depending on the user's input. The vertical edge of each polygon is 1 mile, so If the user enters a line length greater than 1 mile, the line would intersect 2 contiguous polygons. If the lines are less than a mile then they can fit inside a single polygon. The final constraint is that the distance between the horizontal edge of the polygons to the tip ("north" and "south") of the lines should be greater than or equal to 500 feet. Hope this makes sense.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to create lines given a polygon. It's probably not exactly what you want, since your request is quite specific, but hopefully the code is generic enough that you cn adapt it.

```r
library(sf)
library(purrr)
polygon <- st_polygon(list(matrix(c(1,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,1,1), ncol = 2)))

# use polygon bounding box to o compute line parameters
bb <- st_bbox(polygon)
number_of_lines <- 5
line_length <- (bb[["ymax"]] - bb[["ymin"]]) / 1.2
y_offset <- bb[["ymin"]] + (bb[["ymax"]] - bb[["ymin"]] - line_length) / 2

# compute coordinates
xs <- seq(bb[["xmin"]], bb[["xmax"]], length.out = number_of_lines)
ys <- bb[["ymin"]] + line_length
# create a linestring
lines <- purrr::map2(xs, ys, ~st_linestring(matrix(c(.x, .x, .y,y_offset), ncol = 2))) %>% st_sfc(crs = st_crs(polygon)) 

# view
plot(polygon)
plot(lines, col = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image: lines in polygon]

Comment: With little modification to your code, I was able to achieve the desired results. Thank you.

Comment: I'm looking for something quite similar to this. Would you happen to remember what modifications you made to the selected answer? thanks!